# Google apps script Error "UrlFetch failed because too much traffic is being sent to the specified URL."

Tags: google-apps-script

I can not find anything about this error.  The script worked earlier today and I need to run it daily to load files into salesforce.  Is this a google limit, and how do i get past it?

Answer (score 2):

See quota limits [here](https://script.google.com/dashboard) (click on quota tab).

See the first two daily limits on UrlFetch towards the bottom.

To preserve the fidelity of the system for all users, there are some published limits on how much UrlFetch can be invoked by a single user/script.

Comment: We have a google business account.  Does the script automatically have the business limits or do I need to do something special.

Comment: It will automatically use that quota if you are running as a user in that domain.

Comment: When does it reset.  I dont see how i have exceeded any of the limits either yesterday and defiantly not today but am still getting the error.  Right now there are about 350 files i want to move totaling 142 MB.   This is more than a weeks worth of deposits so the nightly payload would be 10 to 20 % of the current total.  I believe the total list will exceed the limits and will take more than one day to catch up.  So far I moved about 11 files, less than 10 mb.  Whats going on?

Comment: Base 64 encoding can cause more than 30% increase in file sizes. So if you try to upload a 7.5mb file (after its converted to PDF), you are likely running into the 10mb limit POST limit. Regarding the timed limits (which doesn't look like what you are running into), I am unclear on that and will check.

Comment: None of my files are over a mb, half are under a 100 kb so cant imagine I am hitting the 10mb post limit.  It ran twice a few minutes ago.  Still debugging code after line 96 so it moved one file each time.  A total of 197kb of pdf data.  Getting the error again.  Is something else going on?

Comment: Also, how do I capture errors like this, log them, exit the program so I can see the results.  I am have set this to run each morning and am sending the log to myseld.  I would like to know when i get errors as well.  I have not seen any code with an error handler in it.  suggestions.